# Boolean values are automatically converting into up case while extracting data from json files using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have below json file which has comment true or false. false is being sent  in the json file for the field :comment

While i am parsing this json data using python pandas data-frame , First letter of value is automatically getting converted into upper case

Example: false -> False , true -> True

First letter of true or false is getting converted into upper case. How can i get exact value as it is "false"

```
{
  "Flag": [
    {
      "Comment": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using below code to print the value

```
# Importing the necessary packages
import json
import sys
import pandas as pd

with open("Json.json") as f:
    json_file = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame()

temp = {}
temp['Flagg'] = json_file['Flag'][0]['Comment']
print(temp['Flagg'])

temp_df = pd.DataFrame([temp])
df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv("FinalTest.csv", index=False, quoting=1)
```

I am getting output = False

But My Expected Output : false

Comment: `false` is Json while `False` is Python. You are converting Json boolean to Python Boolean

Comment: This post may contain some relevant information about the differences between json booleans and python, and how we can still use json input in python with the `json` package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722662/converting-true-json-to-python-equivalent-true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without your code, but my best guess is that in the JSON, you are transmitting the *value* `false`, not the *string* `"false"`. In Python, the boolean values are called `True` and `False`, respectively. (See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for more info.)

If you want the exact value "false", then the sender should be sending the JSON value as a string, not as a boolean type.

Comment: @Thanks a lot Michael. Actually In json file i have string as "false" but while i am parsing it into a output csv file - it is becoming "False"

Comment: @Ravi then please update your post to show the *actual input* you are processing, as well as **your code** being used to process and write.

Comment: @Ravi why wouldn't you want to have Boolean columns though? I am assuming that the data coming in as "Flag" it would make sense to keep it Boolean. Just curious is all

Comment: @MichaelKolber .. I have added code in my question and expected output. Please have a look

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy. Actually this is part of a json file. i need to pick comment value. I have added code as well. As per Json file i have "false" but i am getting output "False"

Comment: @Ravi You say in your comment `Actually In json file i have string as "false"` but the code in your question show that `false` is not being sent as a string, but rather as a boolean JavaScript value. Either your code is wrong or your comment is wrong. If the code you provided is correct, and you can't change the JSON that's being recieved, then you can do something like `if not json_file['Flag'][0]['Comment']: json_file['Flag'][0]['Comment'] = "false"`

Comment: @MichaelKolber. sorry for the incomplete sentence. I mean in the file itself i am getting as    false     (without enclosing in double quotes) . If i print the value i am getting output as     False    ...

Comment: @MichaelKolber . Just to show that as value i have added it as double quotes.

Comment: @Ravi you need to post your code being used to write to the CSV. We can't help you if we don't have your code.

Comment: @MichaelKolber .. It has already complete code. For understanding i have added print as well.

Comment: @Ravi if anything you can always replace `False` with 'false` in your `dataframe` if you want

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy . Without replace is that possible . please suggest